# REST Api Contracts and Documentation

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, documentation

I'm integrating with an external system, they will be able to send a POST request through REST API and create records of a custom object I've created in my org.
I need to send to the client the documentation about all the contracts, the endpoint and all the error or success messages related to this request.
Is there a easy way in salesforce to get the json body they have to send me based on the needed fields? I would like to know if there is also a way to get all the other information like the curl, the error messages etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is in [REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)

[REST by itself is just a way to send HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190836/what-is-the-difference-between-http-and-rest) so curl commands don't differ here from any other. See [Using cURL in the REST Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm) and [Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_user_tasks.htm) sections from the documentation.

Errors are indicated by standard HTTP status codes which you can find on [Wikipedia: List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for instance.

Full reference is here: [REST API Developer Guide: Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm)